# Passing *ngModel and Variable value in Component Method as argument not changing

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a boolean variable. I want to pass this variable in the component method as a method parameter and change its value.

but the value is not getting changed. check m current code below.

**HTML**

```
      <li class="list-group-item" (click)="selectUnselectAll(isAllSelected)">
        <span *ngIf="isAllSelected;else noneSelected">UnSelect All</span>
        <ng-template #noneSelected>Select All</ng-template>
      </li>
```

**Component**

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';

        @Component({
            selector: 'app-root',
            templateUrl: './app.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
        })
        export class AppComponent {
            isAllSelected:boolean;

            constructor() {
                this.isAllSelected = false;
            }


            selectUnselectAll(isAllSelected){
                console.log(isAllSelected);    
                isAllSelected = !isAllSelected;
                console.log(isAllSelected);    
            }
        }
```

here **isAllSelected** is a boolean

**Update: What is required?**

I want to change the value of **isAllSelected**, as "UnSelect All" text does not appear.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: what's the error? code seems fine

Comment: @PardeepJain value of isAllSelected not getting changed from selectUnselectAll method

Comment: Try to  console in function what value you are getting

Comment: @PardeepJain plz check updated Q with image

Comment: yes, getting your point because you are sending params as local but binding is done here using global variable that's the reason, please check my answer below

Comment: The console log is as expected, you change the local variable, but a boolean is a primitive, which means you are passing a variable as a value, not a pointer, and that means your global variable is not updated (unless you set it using the `this`-keyword). If that makes sense :P

Comment: @CodeSpy have you checked my answer?

Comment: found a solution myself as required, I will share in some time thanks for discussions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `this`-keyword, changing the global variable, not the local one to your method

```
selectUnselectAll(isAllSelected){
   this.isAllSelected = !isAllSelected;
}
```

Comment: That works, but I want to change in the local variable passed in the method, not the global variable.

Comment: you are assigning global variable with local variable

Comment: I am not sure how the rest of the code is lined out, but you cannot use the else-if case if you are only changing a variable that is local to the method. The else-if you use in the template only has access to the global variable in your Component

Answer (score 0):

You should use global variable as you are passing local variable but not changes not get reflacted as binding is done using public global variables in Angular. So you code should be like this -

```
  <li class="list-group-item" (click)="selectUnselectAll()">
        <span *ngIf="isAllSelected;else noneSelected">UnSelect All</span>
        <ng-template #noneSelected>Select All</ng-template>
      </li>

      selectUnselectAll(){
          this.isAllSelected = !this.isAllSelected;
      }
```

Or
 if you **don't want to use global variable** then do it like this -

```
<li class="list-group-item" (click)="isAllSelected = !isAllSelected">
    <span *ngIf="isAllSelected;else noneSelected">UnSelect All</span>
    <ng-template #noneSelected>Select All</ng-template>
  </li>
```

No need to call any function.

Comment: In your second example, you are still using the global variable. If you do a `console.log(this.isAllSelected)` in the component after a click, you will see that it is updated as well.

Comment: @John yes, mad bad! you are right, But by doing so you avoid calling function and confusion. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so :)